# Present UIImagePicker inside Modal View

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I pushed modally to a new view controller using:

```
[self presentViewController:picker];
```

and then from within that new view controller I did;

```
  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 picker.delegate = self;
  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But the camera won't even show, why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on iPad and below code worked for me...

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    //present your view controller here...
}];
```

Good Luck !! :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to couple of reasons:

1) Create a method of Camera Opening code:

```
-(void) openCamera {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

And call it like this Wherever you want,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(openCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

OR

2) Write code inside this method,

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

     //... Camera Code ....
```

}];